# CS50P invalid syntax after write exactly as the lecturer's code

Tags: python, cs50

I try to learn Python from CS50P video here https://youtu.be/-7xg8pGcP6w?si=N0TVaGfgLOWrXTqc&t=3264

Typing exactly the code, my result is error

```
students = [
    {"name": "Hermione", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Otter"},
    {"name": "Harry", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Stag"},
    {"name": "Ron", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Jack russel terrier"},
    {"name": "Draco", "house": "Slytherin", "patronus": None}
]
for student in students:
    print(student["name"], student["house"], student["patronus"])
```

Error given:

```
Python 3.12.0 (main, Nov  1 2023, 16:31:09) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>     {"name": "Hermione", "house": "Gryffindor", "Patronus"}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {"name": "Hermione", "house": "Gryffindor", "Patronus"}
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 
>>> python hogwarts.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python hogwarts.py
           ^^^^^^^^
```

Have rechecked several times but can't seem to find where do i do wrong

Please help

I tried to recheck the code given from the lecturer, which i think already exactly the same, but still result in error

update:
Running the code using play button, still resulting in error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd /workspaces/150403671
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?
>>> /usr/local/bin/python /workspaces/150403671/hogwarts.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/local/bin/python /workspaces/150403671/hogwarts.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're already in Python! That's a command-line thing, not a REPL (Interactive Python shell) thing. The `>>>` part means "Enter python code here", while your CLI (shell) normally looks like `$` or `%`. Take that code, save it to the expected filename, then run it with `python` on the CLI.

Comment: thank you, will recheck running it with the button instead of CLI

Comment: @Budi I know it's another thing on the heap of stuff to learn, but you should look in to getting started with an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). Visual Studio Code is free and very powerful. A bit of initial hassle will be worth it.

Comment: Python also has the unique and very powerful [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org) which is a mix between an IDE and a REPL. Worth checking out if you're doing a lot of Python work!

Comment: @Budi.  You should be using the CS50 CodeSpace if possible.  Setup directions here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/0/.  Video short here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/shorts/visual_studio_code_for_cs50/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will check them, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are currently in the Python interactive shell, which lets you execute Python code one line at a time.

You can run the given code in interactive mode. It would look like this:

```
Python 3.12.0 (main, Nov  1 2023, 16:31:09) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>students = [
    {"name": "Hermione", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Otter"},
    {"name": "Harry", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Stag"},
    {"name": "Ron", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Jack russel terrier"},
    {"name": "Draco", "house": "Slytherin", "patronus": None}
]
>>> for student in students:
    print(student["name"], student["house"], student["patronus"])
Hermione Gryffindor Otter
Harry Gryffindor Stag
Ron Gryffindor Jack russel terrier
Draco Slytherin None
>>>
```

Alternatively, exit interactive mode with `exit()` and create a file named hogwarts.py with the full code.  Then from a terminal prompt (not Python interactive mode) type
`python <path_to_file>\hogwarts.py`
replacing <path_to_file> with the actual path.

The core CS50 courses are designed around use of the CS50 GitHub CodeSpace.  Setup directions here You should be using the CS50 CodeSpace if possible.  Setup directions here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/0/

Video short about VsCode for CS50 here:
https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/shorts/visual_studio_code_for_cs50/